# Error while doing aws iam list-users using AWS_CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I am trying to run `aws iam list-users` in the AWS CLI but got an error. The error is:

`An error occurred (SignatureDoesNotMatch) when calling the ListUsers operation: Signature not yet current: 20210606T055848Z is still later than 20210605T174350Z (20210605T172850Z + 15 min.)`

Please if anyone know this solution, please tell to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is pretty clear that the request is signed for `20210606T055848Z` but it "currently" is `20210605T172850Z`. In different format: `05:58:48 @ 06.06.2021` (signed) vs. `17:28:05 @ 05.06.2021` (current). There is a difference of 12 and half hours between the two timestamps.

That means either the local time of your computer / the process creating the request is incorrect or the request is intentionally scheduled for the future and is simply not intended to be submitted yet. Solution: fix your clock, change the code to not sign for the future or submit the request at a later point in time.